# bootstrap KS 2 sample test

Tags: bootstrap, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

I have two datasets $S_1$ and $S_2$. I can run KS 2 samples test on these datasets to obtain the value of the KS 2 samples test.

Is there a correct way to bootstrap the KS 2 sample test using the datasets $S_1$ and $S_2$?

In other words, how exactly should sample from $S_1$ and $S_2$ to obtain a bootstrap distribution for the KS 2 sample test.

For example if we have in scipy the following 2 datasets :

```
from scipy import stats

n1 = 200  # size of first sample
n2 = 300  # size of second sample

S1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n1, loc=0., scale=1)
S2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n2, loc=0.5, scale=1.5)
stats.ks_2samp(S1, S2)
```

Then stats.ks_2samp returns a KS value. I would like to know how could we do bootstrap the samples $S_1$ and $S_2$ to obtain a bootstrap distribution for the ks_2samp values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why isn't enough to have just one K-S test comparing the two samples? I could see the purpose of a simulation procedure if you were trying to find the power of the the K-S test in certain circumstances.

Comment: @BruceET Besides power studies, I have found a few additional reasons to carry out such a procedure.  One is where the two-sample test available does not correctly compute the p-value; for instance, maybe it uses a doubtful approximation or it simply refuses to run with datasets of a certain size.  The other reason is where either of the datasets has a tie, which makes the KS-test inapplicable--but the KS *statistic* may still be useful for distinguishing the underlying distributions.

Comment: @whuber , Do you have an idea for how to carry how bootstrap  in this case? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null hypothesis is that the batches of data are independent simple random samples from a common continuous distribution.  The (two-sample) Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) statistic measures a difference in their empirical distributions.  **Thus, exactly as in any other case where you have a measure of difference, you can bootstrap it by resampling from the combined dataset.**

**There's a slight problem:** about $1/e\approx 37\%$ of a bootstrap sample will be duplicated, which is bad news for the KS test: many implementations will complain.  One workaround is to add a tiny amount of noise to each resampled value.  This is legitimate because adding a tiny bit of noise will scarcely change the underlying distribution (provided it has no discrete components).

(**Another attractive alternative** is to perform a permutation test in which one "bootstrap" sample is obtained *without* replacement from the combined dataset and is compared to the remainder of the data. If there are no ties the combined dataset, there will never be a problem with the KS statistic.  The permutation test and bootstrap perform very nearly the same.)

**Below is an example** in `R`, commented and coded to port readily to Python. It works by concatenating the two datasets into an array `S` and sampling from this array (or, literally, from its indexes using `sample.int`).  Its output documents bootstrapping five situations like the one in the question, giving some indication of the power of the test (that is, its likelihood of rejecting the null).  A bootstrap of 500 resamples would be more than enough, but here I show 5000 resamples to create precise results.

[image: Figure]

(The code will perform a permutation test by setting `do.bootstrap` to `FALSE`.  If nothing else is modified, the same random datasets will be generated, enabling direct comparison between the bootstrap and permutation test results.)

```R
ppts <- function(n) (1:n - 1/2)/n
stat <- function(S1, S2, tol=1e-4) {
  sigma <- sd(c(S1,S2)) * tol # (See the text)
  X1 <- S1 + rnorm(length(S1), 0, sigma)
  X2 <- S2 + rnorm(length(S2), 0, sigma)
  ks.test(X1, X2)$statistic
}

do.bootstrap <- FALSE # Alternatively, use a permutation test.

par(mfcol=c(2,5))
set.seed(17)
seeds <- round(runif(5)*2^31)
n1 <- 10
for (i in 1:5) {
  #
  # Generate data.
  #
  set.seed(seeds[i])
  n2 <- round(n1 * 3/2)
  S1 <- rnorm(n1, 0, 1)
  S2 <- rnorm(n2, 0, 1.5)
  #
  # Compare the data graphically.
  #
  qqplot(S1, S2, bty="n", main="QQ Plot")
  abline(0:1)
  #
  # Bootstrap the statistic.
  #
  S <- c(S1, S2)
  boot <- replicate(5000, {
    if (do.bootstrap) {
      i <- sample.int(length(S), length(S), replace=TRUE)
      stat(S[i[1:n1]], S[i[-(1:n1)]])
    } else {
      i <- sample.int(length(S), n1, replace=FALSE)
      stat(S[i], S[-i], tol=0)
    }
  })
  #
  # Display the bootstrap results.
  #
  ks.data <- stat(S1, S2)
  boot <- c(ks.data, boot)
  p.value <- mean(boot >= ks.data)
  hist(boot, freq=FALSE, breaks=30, col="#f0f0f0", border="Gray",
       main=paste0("P-value is ", signif(p.value, 3)))
  abline(v = ks.data, lwd=2, col="Red")
}
par(mfcol=c(1,1))
```

Comment: thanks man, this is pretty helpful.